# Understanding IEnumerable - IEnumerator logic

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I got stuck with Adam Freeman "Asp net" book, I read a lot about IEnumerable and IEnumerator interface, but it's still hard to understand some results. I have these two classes.

```
public class ShoppingCart : IEnumerable<Product>
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Products.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

and an extension of the first one,

```
 public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static decimal TotalPrices (this IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach (Product prod in products)
        {
            total += prod?.Price ?? 0;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Product is an easy class with some fields like Name, Price etc.
I have lot of doubts. First of all I don't understand how c# knows MyExtensionMethods is an extension of ShoppingCart, then I don't understand how can TotalPrices know that prod come from Products in ShoppingCart class. Could someone explain me briefly the logic behind these few lines?

Thank you everyone, sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: `TotalPrices` is extenstion method for `IEnumerable<Product>`, `ShoppingCart` implements this interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all I don't understand how c# knows MyExtensionMethods is an extension of ShoppingCart

it *isn't*; the "magic" here is the `this IEnumerable<Product> products`, which says "the method is an extension method on anything that is `IEnumerable<Product>`" - and since `ShoppingCart` satisfies that, it works.

> then I don't understand how can TotalPrices know that prod come from Products in ShoppingCart class

It *doesn't* access `Products` on `ShoppintCart`; it goes via `GetEnumerator()`;
this works because `foreach (Product prod in products)` can work on (among other things) something that is `IEnumerable<Product>` - which we know `products` is, because that is how it is defined. This basically then becomes:

```cs
    public static decimal TotalPrices (this IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        using (var iter = products.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                var prod = iter.Current;
                total += prod?.Price ?? 0;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

which is all defined via `IEnumerable<T>`. The good news is: you **usually** never need to know this - just know that `foreach` works on sequences, and `IEnumerable<T>` is a sequence of `T`.